# Dynamic week number in respect to year

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to to retrieve monthly the week number of the year, sounds like a stupid question, but this is what I want to look like:

[image]

For the cell `C1` I have created a drop down list based on `B1 => =TEXT(TODAY();"[$-0809]mmmm")` and also the Weeks (C2:C6) are retrieved by `HLookup` Function.

The idea is that I only need a dynamic Week format, such as C1:C6, but I didn't find another way outside the one I've used and I also need to transpose it in **VBA**. Is there an easier method? I could use your hints/ideas. 
On a new sheet which is exported monthly I need to show the 4/5 weeks of each month, being different from month to month.

Comment: Use the [WEEKNUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/weeknum-function-e5c43a03-b4ab-426c-b411-b18c13c75340) which returns the week number of a specific date.

Comment: The idea is that every month I need on my new worksheet the 4 or 5 weeks of the current month (I've also edited the question, sorry for misunderstanding).

Comment: Yes, as @Pᴇʜ mentioned: Use the [WorksheetFunction.WeekNum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.weeknum) to achieve your goal.

Comment: Yes, that's gonna work just for the moment, in present, but I need it monthly and having all 4 or 5 weeks, like this https://imgur.com/T8qeX08, where in the cell May is placed it has to be a drop-down list with all the months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Weeknum` function: `=WEEKNUM(DATE(2019,3,1),2)` will return the first week of the month and `=WEEKNUM(EOMONTH(DATE(2019,3,1),0),2)` will return the last week of the month.

So put …

- in B2 `=WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),$B$1,1),2 )`
- in B3 `=IFERROR(IF(B2+1<=WEEKNUM(EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),$B$1,1),0),2 ),B2+1,""),"")` and pull it down to get the following result:

[image]

If you now change the month number in B1 it calculates the rest automatically:

Note that there are different official week numbering systems, while the most common would be the [ISO week date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). That means that january 1st is not always week number 1!

Comment: One more thing I want to ask if I may, when transforming this into VBA, I've got an error, is it regarding the fact that I cannot add 1 to the cell just like that? `Range("AQ4").Formula = "=""Total Week "" & IFERROR(IF(AQ1+1<=WEEKNUM(EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY());AW1;1);0);2);AW1+1;"");"")"`

Comment: no you need to change the `;` to `,` because `.Formula` only accepts the original english formula where the separator is `,`. If you plan to use the localized version you must use `.FormulaLocal` instead. But I recommend to use `.Formula` with the english formula so it is independend from any localization and works all over the world.

Comment: Much appreciated! I will note down this observation.

Comment: I have replaced all the `;` with `,` and I still got 1004 error, when I'm trying the formula directly in Excel, it does work `=IFERROR(IF(AQ1+1<=WEEKNUM(EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY());$AW$1;1);0);2);AQ1+1;"");"")`, but when I'm puttin' it in the editor, like this `    Range("AQ4").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(AQ1+1<=WEEKNUM(EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),AW1,1),0),2),AQ1+1,""),"")"`, it crashes.

Comment: all your quotes within the outer quotes need to be doubled: `Range("AQ4").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(AQ1+1<=WEEKNUM(EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),AW1,1),0),2),AQ1+1,""""),"""")"`